# How to execute commands as root using fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to use Fabric to execute some basic commands in a remote server. I haven't used Fabric before and I face some difficulties in executing some commands as.

What I need to do is to connect to the remote server, make a file in a specific directory and then restart the uwsgi server.

Although I am able to do the first two tasks, I can not restart the service as I don't ssh to the server as root user.

This is what I do:

```
def staging():
   env.hosts = ['user@my_host']

def update_app(app_name):
  with cd(git_folder):
    with settings(warn_only=True):
      sudo('mkdir -p /home/new_folder/test')
      #sudo('sudo su -') # also tried this
      sudo('service uwsgi restart')
```

When I include the **sudo su -** command, the fab script is never finished. I just get to be logged in as a root (in the terminal).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `sudo service uwsgi restart`? It should work provided that `sudo` is [configured to allow that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215412/allow-certain-guests-to-execute-certain-commands) without prompting for password.

Comment: When I try this I get: root is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported. Warning: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing 'mkdir -p /home/new_folder/test;sudo service uwsgi restart'!

Comment: Can you _manually_ ssh to the target host and make sure the commands you're going to run can actually be run? Also, if you're running as root already (as it seems), you don't need `sudo`! Try removing it.